# Is there any request method enum in Servlet API?

Tags: servlets

Is there any more elegant way to do that?

```
if (request.getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
   ...
}
```

I mean is there any `enum` or `class` I'm able to use in order to make reference to?

Example:

```
if (request.getContentType().equals(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can use `org.springframework.http.HttpMethod` enum which has `mathces(String method)` and `resolve(String method)` methods. Like: `HttpMethod.OPTIONS.matches(request.getMethod())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any more elegant way to do that?
>
> ```java
> if (request.getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {    
>     ... 
> }
> ```

That's not even correct. In Java, you must use [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) rather than `==` for [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) comparison:

```java
if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {    
     ... 
}
```

> Is there any enum or class I'm able to use in order to make reference to?

In the [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) class you'll find some constants for the HTTP methods, however they are private, so you won't be able to use them.

If you are using JAX-RS, you can use the constants defined in the [`HttpMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/HttpMethod.html). There are constants defined for `DELETE`, `GET`, `HEAD`, `OPTIONS`, `POST` and `PUT` methods. From JAX-RS 2.1, a constant for `PATCH` will be available.